# mutivalue date field search not working

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a multivalue field called freeDaysPool which has multiple dates as strings. With the following code, the search does not return anything. If I leave that field out, the search works just fine with the two other fields. I read that I should use CONTAINS with multivalue fields but then I got query not understandable.

I've tried the back-end field as a date field and as a text field and tested all kinds of query combinations and date formats but no luck. Any help is really appreciated.

This is the search button code:

```
var query = new Array("");
var cTerms = 0;

// Field 1
var search01 = getComponent("searchcustomReservationField01").getValue();
if (@Contains(@Text(search01),"any city")){"";}
else {query[cTerms++] = '[customReservationField01]="' + search01 +'"'};  

// Field 2
var search02 = getComponent("searchcustomReservationField02").getValue();
if (@Contains(@Text(search02),"any city")){"";}
else {query[cTerms++] = '[customReservationField02]="' + search02 + '"'};

// Date 1
var formatter = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("d.M.yyyy");
query[cTerms++] = 'FIELD freeDaysPool = ' + formatter.format(getComponent("searchcustomDateField01").getValue());

// if query is still empty, we fill it with asterisk
if(query == "" || query == null){
    query[cTerms++] = "*";
}
// make all as string
qstring = query.join(" AND ").trim();
sessionScope.searchString = qstring;
```

It will return query as:

```
[customReservationField01]="Oslo" AND [customReservationField02]="Oslo" AND FIELD freeDaysPool = 6.2.2015
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK date values in formulas (and a query is a formula) have to be noted like

```
[06.02.2015]
```

to compare them. Just try to use your formular in the Notes Client to do a fulltext search. If you get results and no errors you found the correct format. That's at least the way I test queries as I'm not able to remind the syntax for years :-D

Comment: Just from curiosity: is it June, or February? :-)

Comment: Thanks Oliver, checking the notes fulltext search was really brilliant idea! @FrantisekKossuth, at least in Finland that is February :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the help! Seems that Domino keeps the field type as date field even if you change it back to text field (noticed that from the notes FTsearch). I created completely new text field and added the days as strings in dd.MM.yyyy format. I also search them as strings and it works fine.
The changed code bit now looks like this:

```
// Date 1
var formatter = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
query[cTerms++] = '[freeDays] CONTAINS "' + formatter.format(getComponent("searchcustomDateField01").getValue())+'"';
```